# Stationary policy assumption in Bellman equation.

Tags: machine-learning

I was checking the proof for the following lemma:

**Lemma.** Suppose that $\pi$ is a stationary policy. Then $V^π$ and $Q^π$ satisfy the following Bellman consistency equations: for all $s \in S$ and $a \in A$,
\begin{align}
V^{\pi}(s) &= Q^{\pi}(s, \pi(s)); \
Q^{\pi}(s, a) = r(s, a) + \gamma \sum_{s' \in S} P(s' | s, a) V^{\pi}(s').
\end{align}**

To prove that, they state that $\pi(s) = \pi(s')$ for all $s$ and $s'$, which is a simplification to consider the average return following the policy $\pi$. I didn't get this, since a policy maps state to actions, how could this assumption of different states be equal following $\pi$?